# How to count the number of rows that meets a specific criteria in R programming?

Tags: r

In this data frame, I'm trying to find the number of right handed batters in the <5 years group without simply counting it manually. Here's a sample of the data:

`Status      Handed 
<5 yrs      Right
<5 yrs      Right
<5 yrs      Left`

How to I use an R function to do that instead of counting it out?

Comment: The dplyr solution: data %>% filter(Status == "5yrs", Handed == "Right") %>%
  group_by(Handed) %>% summarise(count = n())

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
table(df$Handed[df$Status == "<5 yrs"])
```

Or if you want the full breakdown based on Status category, you just do:

```
table(df$Handed, df$Status)
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard solution to count something is `sum`. In this case,

```
sum(df$Handed[df$Status == "<5 yrs"] == "Right")
```

For counting the number of times a condition occurs, `sum` should be your go-to.

`table`, as demo'd in Yannis's answer is useful if you want counts of all possibilities, e.g., `table(df$Handed[df$Status == "<5 yrs"])` gives the counts of Left and Right (and anything else in the handed column, and it is also do crosstabulations, e.g., `with(df, table(Handed, Status))` will give counts of handedness for each of the status categories.

Answer (score 0):

```
**length(df[df$Status=='<5 yrs' & df$Handed == 'Right',])**
```

here df is name of the data frame you are using. This works

Or use sqldf package.

```
**install.packages("sqldf")
**library("sqldf")**
**df$Count=1**
**sqldf("select sum(Count) from df where Status='<5 yrs' and 
  Handed='Right')****
```

Comment: what are all those `**` for?

Comment: you dont need thos **. For some reason, stackoverflow doesnt let me submit the answer without those funny stars.  Just use: length(df[df$Status=='<5 yrs' & df$Handed == 'Right',])